# How do I integrate Google Adsense?

Tags: advertising

How do I integrate Google Adsense? I have installed the Google Adsense module but when I insert the publisher ID, it says I have to insert an ID similar to pub-9999999999999, but Google gave me an ID similar to ca-pub-9999999999999.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s a bug report for a contributed module and needs to be handled in the issue queue on Drupal.org

Answer (score 1):

In the issue queue of the [Google AdSense integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/adsense) module your problem is reported: [Support current CSE code](https://www.drupal.org/project/adsense/issues/3004911)

You could try to create a patch using the suggested information, test it and report back in the issue queue.